# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll - (Visual Basic)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encoding, authentication

so I'm using this tutorial:
http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=442302

It's the only one I could find for a php logins system, everything was going well until i got this error while pressing the "login" button:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
```

I've tried fixing it but I'm pretty clueless to this, I would appreciate help if possible :)

Here's the whole code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Public Class login
    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Process.Start("http://website.co.uk")
    End Sub
    Function CheckUser(AuthenticationPage As String, Username As String, Serial As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim Data As String = String.Format("username={0}&serial={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Serial))
        Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(AuthenticationPage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
        Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        If Response.Contains("Correct") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
    Function AddUser(StoragePage As String, Username As String, Serial As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim Data As String = String.Format("username={0}&serial={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Serial))
        Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(StoragePage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
        Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        If Response.Contains("User added") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
    Function DeleteUser(DeletionPage As String, Username As String, Serial As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim Data As String = String.Format("username={0}&serial={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Serial))
        Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(DeletionPage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
        Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        If Response.Contains("User deleted") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
        If CheckUser("http://website.co.uk/cauth/load.php", login_username.Text, login_password.Text) Then
            'Do whatever you want to do on successful login here.
            MsgBox("You have successfully logged in.")
        Else
            'Do whatever you want to do on un-successful login here.
            MsgBox("You have provided invalid username or password. Unable to login.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why the PHP tag and reference to a "php logins system"? This looks like Visual Basic.

Comment: You messed up your tags : why using php mysql ?

Comment: Damn sorry I thought the tags were just related to the question because the code goes to a php file which goes to my database.

Comment: put a Try/Catch around your login code in the `CheckUser` function and catch the `System.Net.WebException`, set a breakpoint and view the error message